# Can't save map[String,Boolean] to Cassandra using Object Mapper of datastax driver

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax, mapper

I am not able to save `map[String,Boolean]` to Cassandra using Object Mapper of datastax driver. Getting following error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found
  for requested operation: [map<varchar, boolean> <-> 
  java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean>]
```

Comment: The driver has no codec for Scala types. You can either write such a codec yourself or use `java.util.Map` instead.

Comment: Thanks Jubobs!! It works..